# django cms language change

Tags: django, django-cms, language-translation

This is my sort of  setting .py

```
CMS_LANGUAGE_CONF = { 
    'en':['es'], 
    'es':['en'], 
} 

CMS_SITE_LANGUAGES = { 
    1:['en','es'], 
} 
CMS_LANGUAGES = (
    ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
CMS_HIDE_UNTRANSLATED = True
LANGUAGES = [('es', 'Spanish'),('en', 'English')]
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
     # 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware',
    # 'vclubcms.middleware.URLMiddlewares.CustomMultilingualURLMiddleware'
)
```

My problem is :

when i access myserver:8000/myview it renders.
when i access myserver:8000/cmspage it renders
on the cms page templage i have some links . which get converted to `/language_code/cmspage` due to multilingual. so when click on link it is not opening .

e.g. **myserver:8000/language_code/cmspage not working**

What i tried i followed this link 
http://ilian.i-n-i.org/language-redirects-for-multilingual-sites-with-django-cms/comment-page-1/

and enable the

`'vclubcms.middleware.URLMiddlewares.CustomMultilingualURLMiddleware'`

and then i run the myserver:8000/language_code/cmspage

it shows

`The page isn't redirecting properly`

and with 21 request.

Please suggest how can i solve this problem .

Comment: The CustomMultilingualURLMiddleware is used only to add the language prefix to the URL if it is missing. I believe the problem comes from the fact the "myserver:8000/language_code/cmspage" is not working without this middleware. 
Check here I believe the problem is the middleware order prhttp://readthedocs.org/docs/djangocms/en/latest/advanced/i18n.html?highlight=MultilingualURLMiddleware

Comment: @IlianIliev thank you so much , you was right about the problem , problem was in the order .

Comment: Fixed: The problem was in the middlewares order -> for the correct order check http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.2/advanced/i18n.html#multilingual-url-middleware